# Can TamperMonkey create a bookmark?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, opera, tampermonkey, bookmarks

Q:   Is it possible to write a command in that script which automatically saves the original address as a bookmark, in that folder, before redirecting me? I can't find such a command.

Background:

Pretty much new to programming. I'm a student with a broken arm. When I come across an interesting article behind a paywall, I just reload the page using the university's proxy. With one arm broken, I have to do everything with the other hand. So I wrote a javascript in tampermonkey (similar to greasemonkey) which rewrites the URL and loads that page.

To keep track of the articles I've read, I add the address to my bookmarks, in a folder called "Already Read".

Code so far:
(No bookmark command yet.)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Cat.
// @include      https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/*
// @grant        GM_setClipboard
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_deleteValue
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var OldURL = location.href;
     //Saves current URL into a string, "OldURL"
    location.href = OldURL.replace('https://www','http://proxy.ub.umu.se/login?url=https://www');
     //replaces the ScienceDirect domain, replaces it with the university proxy, and loads that address.
```

Desired result: add current page to my bookmarks automatically.

Preferably in a given bookmark folder, but I'd be very grateful to just add the bookmark anywhere. (Having a broken arm is not fun, studying is my catharsis for dealing with the boredom, so I really need to get this.) ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

What I've tried:

I've tried most bookmark related JavaScript commands I could find. (That's how I figured out the rest of TamperMonkey's functions.) But none seem to work.
I've also tried including the commands to allow TamperMonkey to run a script without safety restrictions, such as // @grant GM_deleteValue etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, a Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script cannot add bookmarks because such scripts are unable to affect a browser's "chrome"<sup>(not Google)</sup> UI -- for good reason.

Theoretically, Tampermonkey could make bookmark(s) somewhat more accessible to Tampermonkey scripts [but hasn't so far](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php), and there hasn't been much (¿any?) demand for such a feature until now.

You can (probably/used-to-be-able-to) write a Firefox or Opera extension that does this.

---

Meanwhile, Tampermonkey can keep a list of rewritten URL's but that's a bit more involved to wrap a UI around.

First, use `location.assign()` instead of `location.replace()`, if you are not already.  That way, most of such links will show as visited in your history and on any pages that haven't violated link UI.

Comment: Thanks, dude!
But I figured out a workaround:
The function "GM_openInTab" opens a url in a background tab. All I do now is push ctrl+D, ctrl+W. A one hand operation. It was the constant tabbing that was giving me problems.

Comment: Needs must when the Devil drives.  Glad you got a workaround, @KristerJohnson.